# The Difference Between inner-Join and left-Join When Joining Two Tables with Different Charsets

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL with different charsets: utf8mb4 and utf8. I tried executing join statements using the following SQL code:

```sql
select count(*)
from n_order as o
         left join t_vehicle as v on o.vehicle_license = v.vehicle_license
where o.order_type in (1, 2, 5)
  and o.order_status = 2;
```

The joining key, `vehicle_license`, has the same column type, which is `varchar`, in both tables. However, when executing the left-join statement, the performance is very poor. The execution plan indicates that it requires a `Block Nested-Loop` instead of utilizing the index key.

On the other hand, when executing the inner join statement, MySQL performs normally.

Hence, I wonder if there are any differences between inner-join and left-join when dealing with tables having different charsets.

Comment: The string compare needs in definite collation (comparing rules) to be applied. The values with different charsets cannot be compared directly, the values must be converted to the same charset. If you see Block Nested-Loop or Hash Join then I predict that n_order.vehicle_license is UTF8MB4 and t_vehicle.vehicle_license is UTF8MB3. See the execution plan - with your LEFT JOIN n_order is scanned firstly whereas with INNER JOIN (and RIGHT JOIN) t_vehicle will be scanned firstly. This produces the effect which you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear a speed problem due to charset and collation.  And I hear a `COUNT` problem, but this is based on other issues, especially `LEFT`.

- If `vehicle_license` has a different character set and/or collation between the tables, the `JOIN` (whether Left or Inner) will be very slow.  Fix that.
- Any `COUNT` in a `JOIN` (either kind) first does the `JOIN`, *then* counts.  Depending on the goal, this could be 'correct' or 'incorrect'.
- A `JOIN` builds (logically, at least) an intermediate table with all valid combinations of the rows.  ("Valid, based on `WHERE` and `ON`).  This helps explain the "count inflation" in the previous item.
- `INNER JOIN` (aka `JOIN`) filters out rows.  `LEFT JOIN` includes any rows missing from the 'right' table (`v` in your example).  This wraps up the explanation of why `LEFT` *can* lead to a bigger count.
- As a final tip, the queries may run faster if `n_order` has `INDEX(order_status, order_type)`.